# firefox prints multiple pages rowspan

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a table with a chunk of data in it using related cells via row span.
When printing using the mozilla/ firefox engine as viewed in the print preview there appears to be almost 100 pages to print. with almost just a single line on it.

I did try some table, tr, td, td span level page-break-inside:avoid
But that didn't seem to make much difference.

I've read about just using divs instead of rowspan, divs is how we did it a couple of years ago but there was too much of the items not lining up horizontally by 1 or 2 pixels which made.

This engine is the same that is used for the pdf generator so it's easy for you to see the problem using firefox.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
* {
    font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode, Trebuchet MS;
}
body {
    font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode, Verdana;
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 12pt;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.SpecTable {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
.QIRow {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.LeftColumn {
    text-align: left;
}
.RightColumn {
    text-align: right;
}
.SpecTable td {
    vertical-align: top;
    max-width: 300px;
    min-width: 90px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode, Trebuchet MS;
    font-size: 10pt;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.QIRow.QIBottomBorder2 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
}
span.PDFComment {
    padding-left: 10px !important;
    padding-top: 0px !important;
    display: inline-block;
}
.QIRow span {
    font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode, Trebuchet MS;
    font-size: 10pt;
    padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
}
.QIRow div {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.gggggDesc {
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.SN, .STTName {
    font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode, Trebuchet MS;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding-left: 10px !important;
    display: block !important;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    color: #00699f;
}
.SpecTable th {
    padding: 10px;
    max-width: 300px;
    min-width: 90px;
    font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode, Trebuchet MS;
    font-size: 11pt;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    color: #333333;
}
.ImportantColumn {
    background-color: #F1F6CF;
}
.DarkGreyBackround {
    background-color: #EEEDED;
}
.DarkGreyBackround {
    background-color: #EEEDED;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>    
    <table class="SpecTable" cellpadding="0">
        <colgroup>
            <col width="250"> 
            <col> 
                <col width="180">            <col width="100" class="ImportantColumn"> 
                <col width="180" class="DarkGreyBackround">        </colgroup>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="LeftColumn">xxxx</th>
                <th class="LeftColumn">xxxx</th>
                    <th class="LeftColumn">xxxxx xxxx</th>
                <th class="RightColumn">xxxxx xxx  xxx xxxx</th>
                    <th class="LeftColumn">xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
                <tbody><tr>
                <td class="LeftColumn" rowspan="3">
                            <span class="STTName">xxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxx</span>


                    </td>
                    <td rowspan="3">
                        <div class="gggggDesc">
                            aiaa aaaaiaa Aaaaaaaia Paaa -&amp;abap;<br>
aaAa aAa PAaa aaaaa Paaa A<br>
aa aiaby aaaa, aaaaa aavaaaay aa4a<br>
aaaaa aaa aaiaaiaa aaaaaia aaaaiaa aa aaaa aaaaaaaa.<br>
<br>
Paaiaiaa &amp;aap; aaaaaia aaaa aaaaa aiaa a aiaa aiaaaa aaaaaa ia aaa ia aaiaa.<br>
aaaaaa aaa aaa aa aiaa aaaaaiaa aa aaaaAaaa aaAaa aaaY &amp;aap; aaaaaia aaaa ia aaa paaiaiaa aaaaiaa aaaaa aaaa aaaa ia aaiaa.<br>
<br>
Paaiaiaa &amp;aap; aaaaaia aaaa aa aaaaiaaa aaaaaa ia aaiaa ,aa ia aiaaa aaa,aa ia aaaa aaa aaa aa ia aaaa aaa.<br>
aayaaa &amp;aap; aaaa aa - aaaaa aiaa aaiaa aaap aiaaa aaaaaa aaaaa aa aiaaaa aaaa aiaa aaaaa aiaa aaaP aaaaaia aaaaaa aiaa aiaa<br>
<br>
ia aaiaa.<br>
<br>
aaaaa aaa aaa aaaaa ayaaa baya aaa aaaaaia aaaaiaaa.<br>
<br>
aaaa a5 aaiaaiaa baya ia Yaaaaa aaa aaaaaia aaaa aaaaa aaaa aa baya aaaaa aYaaaa aaaa ia Yaaaaa. aaaaa aiaa aaaa.<br>
<br>
*Aaaa aaaa ba aaaAa, aaaAa &nbsp; aaY baaaaa aaaaaaaiaa jab.<br>
*Qaaaa aaaaaa aaa aaa aiaa viaia aaay.<br>
*Aay aaaiaiaaaa aiaa viaiaa aiaa iaaaa aa aaaaa aaaaaa aa $aaa paa viaia.*Qaaaa aaaaaa aaa aaaaiaa aa aaaaaaa.<br>
*Paiaa aaqaiaaa aaaa aaaaa aay aiaa.<br>aiaa aaaaiaa Aaaaaaaia Paaa&amp;abap;<br>
<br>
-aaaaa aaaaaaaa Paaaiaa Aaaa &amp;abap; &amp;abap;aa aiaby aaaa, aaaaa aavaaaay aa4a aaaa aa7 aaiaaiaa baya ia aaiaa. Paaiaiaa aaa aaaa aa aiaabaaa aaaa ia aaaa &nbsp; aaiaa. apaay a4 aaiaaiaa aaaaaaaa aaavaa ia aaaia Yaaaaa. aaaaa aaa aaa aaaaaia aaaaiaaa ia aaaia aaaaa.<br>aiaa aaaaiaa Aaaaaaaia Paaa&amp;abap;<br>-aaAa aAa PAaa aaaaa Paaa a &amp;abap; &amp;abap;<br>aa aiaby aaaa, aaaaa aavaaaay aa4a<br>aaaa a a45 aaiaaiaa baya ia aaiaa.<br>Paaiaiaa aaa aaaa aa aiaabaaa aaaa ia aaaa &nbsp; aaiaa.<br>PaaAaa aaaa aaIa aaaa aaa Iaaaaaa VAa PAaaIaa aAYa Aaaaaa aaaaIaa<br>aaaaa aaa aaa aaaaaia aaaaiaaa ia aaaia aaaaa.<br>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                            <td class="QIRow LeftColumn QIBottomBorder2">
                                Rear Car Park
                            </td>
                            <td class="QIRow RightColumn QIBottomBorder2">
                                <div>
                                    <span>
xxxxxx
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="QIRow LeftColumn QIBottomBorder2">
                                <span class="PDFComment">Date
cc ccc cccc
ccpcrc
cc ccg cccc
ccocc cccccr
cc-cccc
cccc ccrcccg ccccrcccc Pocc
cc Gcccc Rocc, coccc ccvcrccc cccc
crocc Ccccoccr Pcrcccg crcc
ccrc ccc cccccccg cccc cc ccccc.
Poccccoc ccc ccrc cc cccccccc cogo cc cccc &amp;ccp; ccccc.
cprcc cc cccccccg coccrccc ccrvcc cc coccc ccccoc.
ccccc occ occ ccccccc ccrcccgc cc coccc ccccc.
coc ccccrcpccoc cccccccc cccc Prccc ccoccc
cc pcr cccccrc ccovc c.cc ccc.cc ccc.cc
ccccoccc ccc.cc
coccc Gcc ccc cc.cc
cOccc ccc c,ccc.cc
ccrcc
ccrcc oc Pcccccc crc cc cccc croc ccvoccc cccc.
crcc cccc cc Ccccc, CcccR &amp;ccp; cRc cccorc cocccccccg coc.
ccocc cccocc cor occ cccc vcccc occc.
ccc ccccccoccc cccc vccccc cccc ccccr cc cccrc cccrgc oc cccc pcr vcccc.
ccocc cccocc cor corcccg oc ccccccc.
Pcccc rccccrcc cocr cocrc crc cccc.
</span>
                            </td>
</tr><tr>                            <td class="QIRow LeftColumn QIBottomBorder2">
                                Front Customer Car Park
                            </td>
                            <td class="QIRow RightColumn QIBottomBorder2">
                                <div>
                                    <span>
xxxxxxxx
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="QIRow LeftColumn QIBottomBorder2">
                                <span class="PDFComment">18 Jul 1017
bbpbby
bb bbg bbb7
bbbbb bbbbbb
bb-bbbb
bbbb bbbbbbg bbbbbbbbb Pbbb
b9 Gbbby bbbd, bbbbb Wbvbbbby bbb9
Bbbbb bbb bbbbbbbg bbbbbbb bbbbbbg bb Gbbb bbbbbbbb.
Pbbbbbbb &nbsp; bbbbbbb bbbb bbbbb bbgb 8 wbbb bbbbbb bbbbbd bb bbb bb Wbbbb.
bbbbbb bbw bbb bb bbgb bbbbbbbb bb bbbbbbbb bbbbb bbbY &amp;bbp; bbbbbbb bbbb bb bbb pbbbbbbb bbbbbdb bbbbb gbbb bbbb bb Wbbbb.
Pbbbbbbb &nbsp; bbbbbbb bbbb bb bbbbbgbb bbbbwb bb Wbbbb ,bb bb bbbbb bbw,bb bb bbbb bbw bbd bb bb bbbb bbw.
bbybbb &nbsp; bbbb bb - bbbbb wbdb Wbbbb bbbp bbbbb bbbbbb bbbbb bb bbddbb bbwb wbbb bbbbb bbgb bbbP bbbbbbb bbbbbd wbbb bbbb
bb Wbbbb.
Bbbbb bbb bbd bbbbb bybbb bbyb bbd bbbbbbb bbbbbbgb.
bbbb bb bbbbbbbg bbyb bb Ybbbbw bbd bbbbbbb bbbb bbbbb bdgb bb bbyb bbbbb bYbbbb bbbb bb Ybbbbw. bbbbb bbgb bbbb.
Jbb Dbbbbbpbbbb bbbbbbby bbbb Pbbbb bbbbbb
bb pbb bbbbbby bbbvb b.bb b,bbb.bb b,bbb.bb
bbbbbbbb b,bbb.bb
bbbbb Gbb bb% bbb.bb
bbbbb bbD b,bb8.bb
bbbbb
bbbbb bb Pbybbbb bbb bb dbyb bbbb bbvbbbb dbbb.
bbbb bbbb bb bbbbb, bbbbb &nbsp; DbY bbbbbb bbbbbbbbbg jbb.
bbbbb bbbbwb bbb bbb bbbb vbbbb bbby.
bby bddbbbbbbb bbbb vbbbbb wbbb bbbbb bb bbbbb bbbbgb bb $b8b pbb vbbbb.
bbbbb bbbbwb bbb wbbbbbg bb wbbbbbd.
Pbbbb bbbbbbbb bbbb bbbbb dby bbbb.</span>
                            </td>
</tr>                


    </tbody></table>
</div>






</body>
</html>
```

Comment: aha moment.
Change the span.PDFComment to use 'display:block' instead of 'inline-block'

Answer (score 0):

aha moment. Change the span.PDFComment to use 'display:block' instead of 'inline-block'